# How to integrate KeystoneJs with Sentry.io

Tags: keystonejs, sentry

I integrated projects on other platforms with Sentry before and it is quite simple. But at this time, I'm using [KeystoneJs](https://keystonejs.com), which is created on the top of Express.

Sentry offers this tutorial to let Express users integrate their applications with Sentry: https://sentry.io/for/express/

But it is not clear to me how to apply it on a KeystoneJs project, since we can't just invoke `keystone.use()`

I know we have some hooks available on keystone, so I also tried this:

```
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node'); 
Sentry.init({ dsn: 'https://a43847aba49b41d69b87793e01c008ae@sentry.io/1301672' });
keystone.set('pre:routes', Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());
keystone.set('pre:routes', Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());
```

This lead to this error:

```
TypeError: next is not a function
    at sentryErrorMiddleware (/Users/ronconi/Workspaces/OfficePools/victoria-royals-api/src/node_modules/@sentry/node/src/handlers.ts:268:5)
    at createApp (/Users/ronconi/Workspaces/OfficePools/victoria-royals-api/src/node_modules/keystone/server/createApp.js:119:29)
    at Keystone.initExpressApp (/Users/ronconi/Workspaces/OfficePools/victoria-royals-api/src/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/initExpressApp.js:9:47)
    at Keystone.start (/Users/ronconi/Workspaces/OfficePools/victoria-royals-api/src/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/start.js:47:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ronconi/Workspaces/OfficePools/victoria-royals-api/src/keystone.js:69:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at loader (/Users/ronconi/Workspaces/OfficePools/victoria-royals-api/src/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/ronconi/Workspaces/OfficePools/victoria-royals-api/src/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ronconi/Workspaces/OfficePools/victoria-royals-api/src/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:154:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
```

I'm wondering about the best way to integrate Keystone and Sentry, but I couldn't find it anywhere. If anyone made this before, please let me know!

Next thing I will try it add a separate express app to the project and link it with keystone, like described here: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/wiki/How-to-Add-Keystone-to-an-Already-Existing-Express-App

Since it is not exactly my case, I'm not sure if it is the best way to go or just find a way to use the regular express `app.use()` with KeystoneJs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. No need to add a new express app for this. All I had to do was use `keystone.set()` instead of `app.use()`.

Only note: When working directly with Express, you can add several error handling middlewares while with keystone, I already had something like `keystone.set('500', myCustomErrorHandlingMiddleware);`

So I moved the code to use `sentry.Handlers.errorHandler()` to inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

On Keystone 6, after adding the `Sentry.init` call, you'll have to add two things in order to log both GraphQL errors, and errors that could come from custom endpoints.

In your `keystone.ts` file:

```js
export default config({
  // …
  server: {
    // …

    // Handle express errors:
    extendExpressApp: (app, createContext) => {
      // Must be placed before any other middleware.
      app.use(Sentry.Handler.requestHandler());

     // Your other custom middlewares and controllers…

     // Must be placed after every other controller.
     app.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler();
    }

  // Handle GraphQL errors
  graphql: {
    appolloConfig: {
      plugins: [{
        // Taken from https://blog.sentry.io/2020/07/22/handling-graphql-errors-using-sentry/#reporting-errors-to-sentry-with-apollo-server-nodejs-typescript
        requestDidStart(_) {
          return {
            didEncounterErrors(ctx) {
              ctx.errors.map(error => {
                Sentry.withScope(scope => {
                  scope.setTag('kind', ctx.operation.operation);

                  scope.setExtra('query', ctx.request.query);
                  scope.setExtra('variables', ctx.request.variables);

                  if (error.path) {
                    scope.addBreadcrumb({
                      category: 'query-path',
                      message: error.path.join(' > '),
                      level: severityLevelFromString('debug')
                    });
                  }

                  Sentry.captureException(error);
                });
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```